# C# Bitblit from Bitmap to control (Compact Framework)

Tags: c#, graphics, windows-mobile, bitblt

I used once BitBlt to save a screenshot to an image file (.Net Compact Framework V3.5, Windows Mobile 2003 and later). Worked fine. Now I want to draw a bitmap to a form. I could use `this.CreateGraphics().DrawImage(mybitmap, 0, 0)`, but I was wondering if it would work with BitBlt like before and just swap the params. So I wrote:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
public static extern int BitBlt(IntPtr hdcDest, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, uint dwRop);
```

(and further down:)

```
IntPtr hb = mybitmap.GetHbitmap();
BitBlt(this.Handle, 0, 0, mybitmap.Width, mybitmap.Height, hb, 0, 0, 0x00CC0020);
```

But the form stays plain white. Why is that? Where is the error I commited?
Thanks for your opinions. Cheers, David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this.Handle` is a *Window handle* not a *device context*.

Replace `this.Handle` with `this.CreateGraphics().GetHdc()`

Of course you'll need to destroy the graphics object etc...

```
IntPtr hb = mybitmap.GetHbitmap(); 
using (Graphics gfx = this.CreateGraphics())
{
  BitBlt(gfx.GetHdc(), 0, 0, mybitmap.Width, mybitmap.Height, hb, 0, 0, 0x00CC0020);
}
```

In addition `hb` is a `Bitmap Handle` not a `device context` so the above snippet still won't work.  You'll need to create a device context from the bitmap:

```
    using (Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("c:\test.bmp"))
    {
        using (Graphics gfxBitmap = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap))
        {
            using (Graphics gfxForm = this.CreateGraphics())
            {
                IntPtr hdcForm = gfxForm.GetHdc();
                IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBitmap.GetHdc();
                BitBlt(hdcForm, 0, 0, myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height, hdcBitmap, 0, 0, 0x00CC0020);
                gfxForm.ReleaseHdc(hdcForm);
                gfxBitmap.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: One little comment :) Shouldn't you call ReleaseHdc() on the hdc's you got from the two graphics objects?

Answer (score 2):

You mean something along these lines?

```
    public void CopyFromScreen(int sourceX, int sourceY, int destinationX, 
                               int destinationY, Size blockRegionSize, 
                               CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation)
    {
        IntPtr desktopHwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
        if (desktopHwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
        }
        IntPtr desktopDC = GetWindowDC(desktopHwnd);
        if (desktopDC == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
        }
        if (!BitBlt(hDC, destinationX, destinationY, blockRegionSize.Width, 
             blockRegionSize.Height, desktopDC, sourceX, sourceY, 
             copyPixelOperation))
        {
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
        }
        ReleaseDC(desktopHwnd, desktopDC);
    }
```

FYI, this is [right out of the SDF](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/03/11/ScreenCaptureInTheCompactFramework.aspx).

EDIT: It's not real clear in this snippet, but hDC in the BitBlt is the HDC of the target bitmap (into which you wish to paint).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `this.Handle` refers to a valid device context? Have you tried checking the return value of the `BitBlt` function?

Try the following:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint="CreateCompatibleDC")]
public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hdc);

[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint="GetDC")]
public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

IntPtr hdc     = GetDC(this.Handle);
IntPtr hdcComp = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

BitBlt(hdcComp, 0, 0, mybitmap.Width, mybitmap.Height, hb, 0, 0, 0x00CC0020);
```